# How to Configure Name Servers using Webmin in Unmanaged VPS on Centos

Tags: dns, vps, nameserver, cname, webmin

I want to configure my site's name servers and all related stuff. I'm not able to find any good documentation steps to do it straight-forwardly without understanding the natty-gritty of this. I wish I could afford managed Vps

I feel that I'm the odd one out looking for this documentation.

I've followed doc at these places:

1. http://www.webtop.com.au/blog/how-to-setup-dns-using-webmin-2009052848
2. http://www.beer.org.uk/bsacdns

Comment: If this is just for a single site, I suggest using your domain registrars nameservers or a 3rd party.  It will make your life easier and provides immediate access to change your DNS should your VPS be down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this information from this website: https://www.virtacoresupport.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=134

> - Login to webmin.
> - Click on the Servers Icon once and wait for it to load fully.
> - On that page, locate the BIND DNS Server link and click on it (assume you install BIND version).
> - On the BIND DNS Server page, click on the Create a new master zone and wait for the page to load fully.
>
> Now, the loaded page will show you a form asking for the following:
>
> - **Zone type**: Forward
> - **Domain name / Network**: Enter in your domain name(without the www)
> - **Records file**: Automatic
> - **Master server**: ns1.yourdomain.com (note... this ns should be the one you created atyour domain registrar)
> - **Email address**: //dns@yourdomain.com// (as long as this is your valid email address)
>
> Leave everything else as it is and press on the Create button.
>
> After you have done that, you should
>   be in the Edit Master Zone for your newly added domain. Find Name
>   Server (1) and click on it so that you can add another name server.
>
> In Add Name Server Record page, there is a form there asking for the
>   following:
>
> - **Zone Name**: yourdomain.com. (remember there is one dot . at the end of your domain name).
> - **Name Server**: ns2.yourdomain.com. (this should be your second name server which you have created at your domain registrar.)
> - Leave everything else as it is and click on the Create button.
>
> Ok, you have already added your domain name in BIND and now you need
>   to point your domain name to a valid IP address by doing the
>   following:
>
> - Go to Edit Master Zone page for your domain and click on Address and a form with the following fields will be loaded:
>
> Name: yourdomin.com. (remember the ending dot) Address: your assigned
>   IP address
>
> - Leave everything else as it is and click on the Create button.
>
> Do the above step for your name servers (e.g. the two name servers
>   which you have created at your domain registrar)?
>
> Name: ns1.yourdomin.com. (remember the ending dot) Address: your
>   assigned IP address (the one you assigned when creating this name
>   server at your domain registrar)
>
> Do the same for your ns2.yourdomain.com. ns1/ns2.yourdomain.com are
>   just an example.
>
> If you need to make your domain email to work, this step is important:
>
> - Click on the Mail Server link in your Edit Master Zone for your domain then a form will be loaded asking for the following:
>
> Name: yourdomain.com. Mail Server: yourdomain.com. Priority: 10
>   (should be good enough)
>   * Leave everything as it is and click on the Create button.
>
> If you need other people able to reach your domain site with www in
>   front:
>
> - Create a new Name Alias which can be found in your domain Edit Master Zone page. The form will ask you for the following:
>
> Name: www.yourdomain.com. (again... remember the ending dot) Real
>   Name: yourdomain.com. (remember the dot)
>
> - Once you have done all of the above, you have to start/restart NAME/BIND by going to the Module Index page for BIND then scroll all
>     the way down and find for either Apply Changes or Start Named button.